# Jailbreak - add icon to statusbar

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, theos

I'm working on a tweak for Cydia, I want to add an icon to the status bar.
I've looked thru Google for every possible phrase I can think of for a few hours now, but nothing seems to turn up.

I know it's not possible using the Apple SDK, but I'm looking for a way for jailbreak devices.
I'm using Theos, if it matters.

I'm sorry I can't put up any code, or something to narrow down, but I've really got nothing to show..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [libstatusbar](https://github.com/phoenix3200/libstatusbar). It's unified, safe and maintained continuously.

Comment: I've tried, but I'm having trouble building it for some reason, It says It's missing some files `common.h:22:37: error: UIStatusBarLayoutManager.h: No such file or directory` for example. Is it supported in iOS 6? Cause i've managed to build my tweak using other UIKit files. Thank for you answer

Comment: @Lablabla You're supposed to be able to resolve such a simple error yourself. I don't know what this file/class is, nor what it does, but perhaps forward-declaring it would be enough.